# Create DatePicker with specific date in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

Can I create a `DatePicker` that displays a specific date?

Here is my code:

```swift
struct OnlineShop: View {
  @State private var date = Date()
  var body: some View {
    DatePicker(
      "Start Date",
      selection: $date,
      displayedComponents: [.date]
    )}
}
```

This code displays the current date on the picker. I want to show a specific date, such as 8/29/1987.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just [create your own date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41534001/14351818) and set it.

```
struct OnlineShop: View {
    @State private var date = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, Online!")
        
        DatePicker(
            "Start Date",
            selection: $date,
            displayedComponents: [.date]
        )
        .onAppear {
            let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
            let components = DateComponents(year: 1987, month: 8, day: 29)
            if let customDate = calendar.date(from: components) {
                self.date = customDate /// set customDate to date
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Date picker shows "Aug 29, 1987"]

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. You can specify any component(s), like the year, month, day, hour, etc. using the `DateComponents` initializer with `Calendar.current`.

You need to initialize your `date` variable like so:

```swift
@State private var date: Date = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 1987, month: 8, day: 27)
```